# Implementing programmatically UIView over a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to understand which methods of UIView I must override to be able to display something.

I have a very simple application that:

1. Has a single UIViewController
2. Has a UIView
3. The UIView creates an offscreen image with the size of the View and the image is drawn in drawRect

Questions:

1. How should I create the view? Calling initWithRect? Or just init? I want to do it programatically, no storyboard nor nibs.
2. What method of UIView is called when the UIViewController sets the view bounds? And how can I get these bounds (to be able to create the offscreen image).
3. Does someone know where can I find the source for UIImageView?

Note: I've been trying to do this for 4 days, without success.

Comment: Is the image an existing resource, or are you programmatically creating it with CoreGraphics calls? Have you explored just using an instance of UIImageView as a subview of your view, where imageView.frame = mainView.bounds?

Comment: I'm creating it using a bitmap thats filled with data, and transformed into an UIImage to draw on screen.

Answer (score 3):

1.) `initWithFrame:`

1.) By default, there is no method that's automatically called when bounds are set. If you subclass the `UIView` you can override the `setBounds` method if you wish.

2.) Sources for `UIImageView`?..The header class is available in the `CoreFoundation.framework`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. When i call initWithCGImage i dont need to specify the view bounds. Are the frame bounds set to the image bounds? The idea of using an UIViewController was to let the controller define the view bounds.

Answer (score 0):

That's how i m using UIView in UIViewController and added UIImageView and UITextView as subview of UIView in UIViewController didn't showed code for UITextview because you are not asking about it in your question.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:baseView];
    [baseView release];

    // Displays UIImageView
    UIImageView* ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 235)];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    // load all the frames of our animation
    ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"1a.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"1b.png"],
                                    nil];

    // all frames will execute in 25 seconds
    ImageView.animationDuration = 25; 

    // start animating
    [ImageView startAnimating];
    ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    ImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    [ImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [ImageView.layer setCornerRadius:15.0f];

    [baseView addSubview:ImageView]; 
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `-(void)loadView` in your custom ViewController class:

```
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.view = baseView;
[super loadView];
```

From there you can create a custom UIView that adds the view property of that ViewController.